# PHP - Executing a task on users click only once

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I am working on a functionality that is similar to the facebook's like function. There is a login and SESSION and everything, but the problem is, once a user sign in, he can click the like several times over and the value gets updated every time. I do not want this to happen. I want the user to click like only once for that particular code. After that, nothing should happen even if the user clicks it again. I searched for this on the internet, but I found many complicated answers that either didn't work or were too hard to understand.
I would appreciate it if the answer was given in terms of PHP or JavaScript.

Here is the code:

```
$likes = $row['like'];
if(is_null($likes)){
    echo "<p>No Likes Yet.</p>";
}else{
    echo "<p style='display: inline; color: #808080;'>".$likes."  Likes</p><br>";
}
echo "<br><a href='like.php?id=".$id."'><img src='images/like.png' style='width:30px; height: 30px; margin-left: 10px;'/></a>";
?>
```

Please note that the like.php in the above anchor tag is where the Like is updated into the database.

Comment: Utilize local storage or session storage for that

Comment: Are the likes being stored anywhere?

Comment: You can put user id and the post id into a table which has two primary keys of both columns (user_id, post_id). The question is very broad for such mechanism, but these are the leads. Good luck.

Comment: You have a SQL tag so you're already aware of databases. You have user sign in so you already know who's voting. Can't you just store votes in a database?

Comment: @thebluefox The likes are being stored in the database according to the last sentence in the OP.

Comment: I am storing the votes in the database, and the tables for the user login credentials and storing the content and their corresponding likes are different. So i am having the difficulty of tracking the likes

Comment: The content and their corresponding likes should be stored in different tables; for example a table that links a like-content-id to a user-id. Then you can easily count and check if an entry already exists.

Comment: You have the like saved - so you should be able to query the DB to see if that user has liked that post (or whatever) previously. To solve the issue of multiple clicks - personally I'd replace the <a> with the a non-clickable version from within the JS function that handles the actual Like action.

Comment: You can use a count query... if a record for particular user is already exist then don't add it again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the users actions in a table, it's very easy. You create a new table to record the 'user_id' and the 'item_id' that he clicked 'like'. Then you can use a php function the check this table when a users visits or tries to like the item again, if he already did you can remove the link and simply don't let the like sum.

The function to check is something like:

```
function checkUserAction() {
        $actionQuery = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM actions WHERE user_id={$_SESSION['user']} AND item_id = {$_GET['item']}");
        $actionTotal = mysql_fetch_array($actionQuery);
        return $actionTotal['total'];
    }
```

The function returns the number of likes of a user to an item. If he already likes it would be 1, if not 0. With this you can do a true or false check to display or not the link:

```
if(checkUserAction()) { // if true don't link

echo "<br><img src='images/like.png' style='width:30px; height: 30px; margin-left: 10px;'/>";

} else { // if false link

echo "<br><a href='like.php?id=".$id."'><img src='images/like.png' style='width:30px; height: 30px; margin-left: 10px;'/></a>";

}
```

If he already clicked you can display another image to let him know.

To record the actions you need to do a simple insert query when you record the number of likes:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO actions(user_id,item_id) VALUES({$_SESSION['user']},{$_GET['item']})");
```

UPDATE: This is a rough sketch of how to store the likes of a user in a single row to avoid creating thousands of rows. In the table the field 'likes' should be change to a VARCHART field to store a string of numbers:

```
// The first time a user likes INSERT a new row
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test.doarray(user,likes) VALUES(1,'25,12')");
// New likes are added with CONCAT() separated with commas (or other char you choose)
mysql_query("UPDATE test.doarray SET likes = CONCAT(likes,',24,53') WHERE user = 1");
// Now when you fetch the data you can transform it in an array using explode()
$doQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test.doarray WHERE user = 1");
while($doFetch = mysql_fetch_array($doQuery)) {
    $result = explode(",",$doFetch['likes']);
}
print_r($result);
```

Now you can check if the item is already liked using:

```
in_array($_GET['item_id],$result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried what you have told, and it works. But the only thing that concerns me is, every time a new user clicks on the like button, a new row is created in the actions table, and this goes on for different posts, and different users. Is this not going to be a problem later on, if there are like a million users? :) This is just my speculation. I may be wrong though.

Comment: You're right. I edited to add an idea of how to store the likes in a single row per user. It's a little more tricky to do, but it can be done ;)